# Run filter if only it was run from specific admin page ( 'upload_dir' changed )

Tags: admin, uploads, media

The situation is following:

In WordPress, there is a plugin page created with optionality to upload media files.  The code added to this plugin, that changes the upload directory by adding of filter .

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'change_upload_dir', 10, 1 );
```

And the uploading directory for media is changed.

The question is how to make this filter run only from this admin page, not other like pages or posts, because, when you creating a new post or page (and upload media), it executes the filter from WordPress custom admin plugin and change the upload directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding filter:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'change_upload_dir', 10, 1 );
```

Function content:

```
 function change_upload_dir($param) {
        // Check for REFER
        $actual_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        parse_str( parse_url($actual_page, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query_array );

            if ( strpos($actual_page, 'plugin_name.php') ) {
            $mydir         = '/customdir';
            $param['path'] = $param['basedir'] . $mydir;
        }

        return $param;
    }
```

Hope this will help

Other ideas, based not on HTTP_REFERER, are appreciated :)

Comment: Take a look at `get_current_screen()`. You might want [to use the "Current Admin Info"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) plugin to get a bit more insights on what is present on admin pages.